# Can't figure it out how to <s:select>

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, select, struts2

Trying to get list of companies in `select` but it gives me an error.

```
type Exception report

message tag 'select', field 'list', name 'workOrder.company': The requested list key          
'listAllCompanys' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator
   type.   Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]

description
   The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

**Exception:**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: tag 'select', field 'list', name 'workOrder.company': The requested list key 'listAllCompanys' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:585)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
```

my `workOrder.jsp` file containing :

```
<s:select list="listAllCompanys"  listValue="companyName" name="workOrder.company"></s:select>
```

When I have a new work order to add, there should be a list of companies available in select .

UPDATE:

Here's my `listAllCompanies()` method

```
public List<Company> getCompanyList() {
    return companyList;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////

public List<Company> getListAllCompanys() {
    return listAllCompanys;
}

private List<Company> listAllCompanys;

public String listAllCompanys() throws Exception
{
    CompanyDaoHibernate dao = new CompanyDaoHibernate();
    listAllCompanys = dao.getListOfCompanys();

    return SUCCESS;

}
```

`CompanyDAOHibernate`:

```
public List<Company> getListOfCompanys()
{

    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session =  sf.openSession();

     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Company>  returnList =  (List<Company>)session.createCriteria(Company.class).list();
    session.close();
    System.out.println("Printing companies... "+returnList);
    return returnList;

}
```

Comment: Please post java file which having listAllCompanys() method

Comment: @Ramesh just posted my java file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSP contains a select tag returned by the action. When you add an order it should have a `list` attribute bound to the bean property. It should be a `top` object in the value stack.

In most cases initializing that property in the action class better to implement [`the preparable interface`](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/preperable-interface.html) where you have to write `prepare()` method and initialize the list.

The exception is thrown because the `list` attribute of the `s:select` tag couldn't be `null`. You should properly initialize the variable used for the tag before returning a result that has references to that variable.

Comment: I probably have wrong hibernate request and it causes this error. I'll check it out.