# How to invoke Action class creation in Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, configuration, struts2, action

I have login and calculation JSP pages. Calculation page contains list, which needs initialized action object. Here is `login.xml`

```xml
<struts>
  <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="*Action" class="com.task.action.{1}Action">
        <result name="success">/calculation.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/login.jsp</result>
    </action>
  </package>
</struts>
```

**calculation.jsp:**

```jsp
<s:form action="CalculationAction">
    <s:select label="Types" 
    list="calculationTypes" 
    name="calculationType" value="getDefaultCalculationType"/>
    <s:submit />
</s:form>
```

After executing LoginAction class, i got "success" and move to calculation.jsp. Problem is CalculationAction is not created, and list in jsp can't initialize. If i call `http://localhost:8082/Task/CalculationAction.action` , jsp page is creating correctly.
I also tried to make references in login page and it works too.

```jsp
<s:url id="calculationUrl" action="CalculationAction">  </s:url>

<div class="tab-wrapper">
    <a href="login.jsp">Login Page</a> 
    <s:a href="%{calculationUrl}">Calculation Page</s:a>
</div>
```

How to make the program working correctly after executing `LoginAction`?

Comment: You have a `.jsp` rendered by your `LoginAction` - this is the one that needs to provide the `list`! Otherwise your `LoginAction` needs to forward to the `CalculationAction` so that it can create the model.

Comment: Just use `redirectAction` result with redirection to `CalculationAction` on success.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26525161/573032

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more result for `LogingAction` to redirect to `CalculationAction`, and return this result instead of `"success"` in the `LogingAction`.

```xml
<action name="*Action" class="com.task.action.{1}Action">
    <result name="success">/calculation.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/login.jsp</result>
    <result name="successfulLogin" type="redirectAction">CalculationAction</result>
</action>
```

The `CalculationAction` on `"success"` should return a `calculation.jsp` and calculation action will be in the value stack, so you can get `calculationTypes` initialized when the action was executed.