# ArrayList of ArrayList in Select Tag in Struts2

Tags: java, select, arraylist, struts2, struts-tags

When I am trying to display `<select>` tag with list contains nested `ArrayList`s.

```java
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> districts=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

districts array list will be like this  `[ [0,"one"],[1,"two"],[2,"three"] ]`

when I am using Struts 2 `<s:select>` tag like below:

```jsp
<s:select label="District" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select State"  list="districts" >
```

it will generating code like this :

```html
<select name="" id="">
    <option value="-1">Select State</option>
    <option value="[12, Anantapur]">[12, Anantapur]</option>
    <option value="[10, Chittoor]">[10, Chittoor]</option>
    <option value="[04, East Godavari]">[04, East Godavari]</option>
    <option value="[07, Guntur]">[07, Guntur]</option>
    <option value="[11, Kadapa]">[11, Kadapa]</option>
    <option value="[06, Krishna]">[06, Krishna]</option>
    <option value="[13, Kurnool]">[13, Kurnool]</option>
    <option value="[08, Prakasam]">[08, Prakasam]</option>
    <option value="[09, S.P.S Nellore]">[09, S.P.S Nellore]</option>
    <option value="[01, Srikakulam]">[01, Srikakulam]</option>
    <option value="[03, Visakhapatnam]">[03, Visakhapatnam]</option>
    <option value="[02, Vizianagaram]">[02, Vizianagaram]</option>
    <option value="[05, West Godavari]">[05, West Godavari]</option>
</select>
```

But I want `01,02,03...` as value names as to display in select tag.

My `Action` Will be Like This:

```java
package authentication;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import Testing.Database_Access;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class Reports extends ActionSupport{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    //private String district;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> districts;
    
    public String dbDistricts(){
        districts=Database_Access.getDbDistricts("01");
        return SUCCESS;
        
    }

    public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getDistricts() {
        return districts;
    }

    public void setDistricts(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> districts) {
        this.districts = districts;
    }

    

    /*public String getDefaultDistrict() {
        return "Select State";
    }

    public void setDistrict(String district) {
        this.district = district;
    }*/

    

}
```

and `struts.xml` is like this:

```xml
<action name="Reports" class="authentication.Reports" method="dbDistricts">
    <result name="success">/Reports.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Here is my Struts2 select tag:

```jsp
<s:select label="District" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select State"  list="districts" >
```

I want the result like this:

```html
<select name="" id="">
        <option value="-1">Select State</option>
        <option value="12"> Anantapur</option>
        <option value="10"> Chittoor</option>
        <option value="04"> East Godavari</option>
        <option value="07">Guntur</option>
        <option value="11">Kadapa</option>
        <option value="06"> Krishna</option>
        <option value="13">Kurnool</option>
        <option value="08">Prakasam</option>
        <option value="09"> S.P.S Nellore</option>
        <option value="01"> Srikakulam</option>
        <option value="03">Visakhapatnam</option>
        <option value="02"> Vizianagaram</option>
        <option value="05">West Godavari</option>
     </select>
```

Comment: Why list of list? Use a map.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26525161/573032).

Comment: Thank you sooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo much..................yaaa i suceeded in this.........................finally it worked by using Map ..................thank you ...........

Comment: @KalishavaliShaik You can put your comments with thanks directly to the person who helped you under his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make a new map like

```
 private Map<String, String> districts;
 //getter here
```

And the `<s:select>` tag

```
<s:select list="districts" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select State"/>
```

Learn more about struts  [`<s:select>` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/select-tag.html):

> Render an HTML input tag of type select.

Comment: @AleksandrM What do you mean?

Comment: Edit history is kept for a reason.

Comment: @AleksandrM and what? Also your comment was not helpful to me, because you edited it after I posted this answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105373/discussion-between-roman-c-and-aleksandr-m).

Comment: You should mark the answer as accepted, if you don't know how to do that see stackoverflow.com/tour