# Multiple checkboxes in different rows with struts

Tags: jsp, checkbox, struts2, checkboxlist

I'm using struts2 to develop some web application and, at some point, I need to get some data from the user: preselect options (with combobox) and some checkboxes.

Both the options (combobox) and the checkboxes are fulfilled with values from MySQL (and working fine)... but when showing the checkboxes I want to show each checkbox in a different line (or row) and this is only happening if I use s:checkbox and s:iterator ... but after that I'm not able to retrieve the values.
However, if I use s:checkboxlist (without s:iterator) all the checkboxes are in the same line and I'm able to retrieve the values in the landing page.

This is my action class where I get the values from DB to show checkboxes:

```
private List<String> listaAsignaturasHabilitadas = new ArrayList();
private List<String> listaAsignaturasHabilitadasSeleccionadas = new ArrayList();

//getters & setters
```

This is showing the checkboxes one per line (but I cannot retrieve it in the landing page):

```
<s:iterator value="listaHabilitaciones" var="habilitacion" status="rowstatus">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="habilitacionSeleccionada" value="${habilitacion}" 
    id="habilitacionesSeleccionadas[${rowstatus.index}]"/>
<s:property value="habilitacion"/>
</label>
<br>
</s:iterator>
```

This is showing the checkboxes in the same line (but I'm able to retrieve it in the landing page):

```
<br><s:checkboxlist label="Escoge" list="listaHabilitaciones" name="habilitacionesSeleccionadas" /><br>
```

This is the landing page:

```
Habilitaciones seleccionadas <s:property value="habilitacionesSeleccionadas"/><br><br>
```

I want to have the checkboxes in different lines and be able to get those check/unchecked values in the landing page.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26525161/573032

Comment: Hi @RomanC! And thanks for your comment. I've read the post and I cannot figure out what should I do. I can get the values from the DB, and I create the list and the select with the action... but I cannot get the list in the landing page if I use checkboxlist (and I DO can get the list if I use checkbox). Can you please help me out? Thanks!